# Job reschedule itself after completion using Quartz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, infinite-loop

I want to run a job and, as soon as it finishes, it should start again, forever.

How can I manage this using Quartz?

Further information will be provided if requested.

Thanks

Comment: So why does it finish - just let it repeat its task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll want to look at the TriggerBuilder which can build a trigger with repeatsForever() to get a repeating job.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/index.html?org/quartz/Trigger.html

```
     JobDetail job = newJob(MyJob.class)
         .withIdentity("myJob")
         .build();

     Trigger trigger = newTrigger() 
         .withIdentity(triggerKey("myTrigger", "myTriggerGroup"))
         .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
             .withIntervalInHours(1)
             .repeatForever())
         .startAt(futureDate(10, MINUTES))
         .build();

     scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Comment: I can't use it like that because of the withIntervalInHours. That way, my job won't restart as soon as it finishes, but will wait for the whole hour.

Comment: how about replacing that as:    Trigger trigger = newTrigger() 
         .withIdentity(triggerKey("myTrigger", "myTriggerGroup"))
         .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
             .withIntervalInSeconds(1)
             .repeatForever())
         .startAt(futureDate(10, MINUTES))
         .build();

Comment: That way the jobs could overflow. We, used a configuration that waits for the completion of the task before rescheduling it using your method, so you got the answer. Thanks!